# vs code takes long time to load variables in the first launch in React Native DEBUG mode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image]

Hi forks,

I am having a problem of taking unreasonable long time to wait the vs code debugger to load the variable values in React Native debug mode. It is only the first launch of my react native App (Running in a device).

Any clue of the causes of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

upgraded as to new vscode version seems fixed this issue. Thanks vscode team.
[image]